# click on button dont trigger jquery function

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a Partial View in my MVC webshop that displays my shopping cart, but for some reason I'm not able to click the "trash" button.

This is my current code.

```html
@model ShoppingCart
@foreach (var product in Model.Items)
{
    <li>
        <div class="b-cart-table ">
            <a href="#" class="image">
                <img width="70" height="70" src="@product.ImageUrl" alt="/">
            </a>
            <div class="caption">
                <a class="product-name" href="#">@product.Name</a>
                <span class="product-price">@product.Quantity x $ @product.Price.ToString("00.00").Replace(",", ".")</span>
                <div class="rating">
                    <span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                    <span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                    <span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                    <span class="star"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
                    <span class="star star-empty"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button onclick="remove();" class="btn btn-remove removeitem"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg"></i></button>
        </div>
    </li>
}
<li>
    <div class="products-subtotal text-right">
        Cart Subtotal <span class="subtotal-price">$ @Model.TotalPrice().ToString("00.00").Replace(",", ".")</span>
    </div>
</li>

@section scripts{
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", ".removeitem", function () {
            alert($(this).text());
        });

        var remove = function(){
          alert("trigger");
        }
      };
    </script>
});
```

I know that there is multiple click / function on the button but its just to show what I have tried so far.

Comment: This should work, for this case, you could also use
$(".removeitem").click(function () { console.log("Event ok"); });

I advise you to use console.log() instead of alert(), see console and developer tools by pressing F12. You remove() function can be called due to the context it is defined, put it out of ready() in the global context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm kinda sure its your:

```
@section scripts{
}
```

I can't explain 100% why but when I use this inside a partial View I cant make my code work either. Try remove your code to your layout page or the page that contains the partialview and try then.

Comment: That worked, I moved my script to the page that contains the partial view and it works now. Thanks alot

Answer (score 3):

You have a typo error when you init the document ready function, it should be this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

}); // here is your error
```

Also, change the name of the function because `remove()` is a jQuery function.

**Fiddle** : https://jsfiddle.net/64pmstja/9/

**Source :**
https://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: Change the name of the function because `remove()` is a jQuery function. Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/64pmstja/9/

Answer (score 1):

The method you are using remove() is a jquery method to remove or delete an element from DOM itself.
All bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements will be removed.
https://api.jquery.com/remove/